# Using SED to uncoment a config file line, and replace text in a Linux config file

Tags: text-processing, sed, sshd

I am trying to automate configuraiton of certain parameters in my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file, most notably the

```
#PermitRootLogin yes
```

and

```
#LoginGraceTime 2m
```

They should read:

```
PermitRootLogin no
LoginGraceTime 60
```

I'm no scripting whiz so please bear with me...

I have tried `sed -e 's/#LoginGraceTime 2m/LoginGraceTime 60/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config` to start the ball rolling, but I get a strange result. It simply cats out the file I am trying to work on...

Can someone set me straight on using sed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redirect the output to a temporary file, then rename the temporary file to the original file

```
sed -e 's/#LoginGraceTime 2m/LoginGraceTime 60/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config > /etc/ssh/sshd_config.tmp && mv -f /etc/ssh/sshd_config.tmp /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Or if you have GNU `sed` you can use the `-i` option for in-place editing

```
sed -i -e 's/#LoginGraceTime 2m/LoginGraceTime 60/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly...

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @Bodo's answer, but this solution leaves the original line untouched and adds the modified version below the original line. This only makes sense if you want to keep the original line as comment.

```
 sed -i'' -n 'p;s/#\(LoginGraceTime\) 2m/\1 60/p;s/#\(PermitRootLogin\) yes/\1 no/p' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Here we use one capturing group `\(...\)` which is substituted by `\1` in the replacement (because we're too lazy to type the same string again).

Sed with option `-n` only outputs the lines explicitly printed, so the first `p` is used to print the unmodified lines and the next two commands to print the modified lines.